# Testing React components with Enzyme when component uses events

Tags: reactjs, typescript, enzyme

I've been having a lot of trouble testing my react components that take advantage of events, most specifically `event.target` . For example when testing the component below;

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { generateGuid } from '../../../utilities/GuidGenerator';

export interface Props {
    dropdownToggle: JSX.Element;
    dropdownMenu: JSX.Element;
}

class Dropdown extends React.PureComponent<Props, object> {

    id = "d".concat(generateGuid().slice(0, 7));

    componentDidMount() {
        window.addEventListener("click", this.hideMenu);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        window.removeEventListener("click", this.hideMenu);
    }

    state = {
        display: { "display": "none" }
    }

    toggleDropdown = () => {
        var display = this.state.display.display === "none" ? "block" : "none";
        this.setState({
            display: { "display": display }
        });
    }

    hideMenu = (e: MouseEvent) => {
        if (!(e.target as HTMLElement).closest(`#${this.id}`) && !(e.target as HTMLElement).closest(".noClose")) {
            this.setState({
                display: { "display": "none" }
            });
        }
    }

    public render() {
        return (
            <div className="dropdown" >
                <div id={this.id} className="dropdownToggle" onClick={this.toggleDropdown} >
                    {this.props.dropdownToggle}
                </div>
                <div style={this.state.display} className="dropdownMenu" onClick={(e: any) => { this.hideMenu(e) }} >
                    {this.props.dropdownMenu}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Dropdown;
```

...with the test below

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as Enzyme from 'enzyme';
import * as Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import Dropdown from './Dropdown';

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

var dropdown = Enzyme.mount(<Dropdown dropdownMenu={<div></div>} dropdownToggle={<div></div>} />, { attachTo: document.body });

describe('Dropdown', () => {
    test('dropdownMenu onClick function sets display to { "display": "none" } if parent is not toggle and doesn\'t contain noClose class', () => {
        dropdown.find('.dropdownToggle').at(0).simulate('click');
        expect(dropdown.find('.dropdownMenu').at(0).prop("style")).toHaveProperty("display", "block");
        dropdown.find('.dropdownMenu').at(0).simulate('click');
        expect(dropdown.find('.dropdownMenu').at(0).prop("style")).toHaveProperty("display", "none");
    });
});
```

I get the error "TypeError: e.target.closest is not a function". Of course it is and it works in the browser, it doesn't seem like Enzyme fires the event off in the same way. I'm having this issue or similar on a few of my components, does anyone know how to resolve this or a workaround? Some of these types of issues were resolved by adding `{ attachTo: document.body }` to Enzyme's mount method but not this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firing an event in enzyme does not the same as in the browser, actually it just take the `onClick` function and call it. So if your event realys on the event object you have to pass it by yourself:

```
 dropdown.find('.dropdownMenu').at(0).simulate('click' { 
  target: { 
    closest:() => {}
  })
```

Also have a look at the [docs](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/simulate.html#simulateevent-mock--self) for `simulate`